# C++/Cli log function (a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class)

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have the following member function in a c++/cli winform class:

```
void loginfo( std::string pMessage)
{
              richtextbox1->AppendText(gcnew String(pMessage.c_str()));
}
```

I want to log messages from a job done by a function with following signature:

```
void getResult(std::function<void(std::string)> func)
```

Inside a button click event I call getResult, trying to pass loginfo function as a parameter:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

 getResult(loginfo);

}
```

Intelisense is marking the line getResult(loginfo) with the Error:a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to convert logInfo to become `static` function, i.e.

```
static void loginfo( std::string pMessage)
```

Comment: But if I convert to static, I will no longer have access to instance member richtextbox1, isn't it?

Comment: You can make your richtextbox1 as one of the `logInfo` function argument.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.   To include richtextbox, I should change the signature for:  getResult(std::function<void(std::string)> func)  , but it resides in an unmanaged class. I don't think I can add System::Windows::Forms:RichTextBox as a parameter.  Are there other alternatives?

Comment: I am not too sure what you try to achieve. But if I were you, I will call `loginfo(getResult())` in `button1_Click` function, where you need to modify it as `std::string getResult()`.